# Moment js not working as expected

Tags: momentjs

I have a date object:

```
Sun Apr 20 2014 11:48:33 GMT-0400 (EDT)
```

I want to be able to simply render the 3 letter month and date, such as "Apr 20"

I am trying to use Moment.js to accomplish this task, like so:

```
moment(date_var).format('MMM D');
```

which spits out: "Jun 25" instead of the expected "Apr 20".

running:

```
JSON.stringify(date_var)
```

produces:

```
2014-04-20T15:48:33.000Z
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Nfmns/3/

Html:

```
<strong>JavaScript </strong><span></span>
<br/>
<strong>Moment </strong>
<p></p>
```

Code:

```
$(function(){
var day = new Date(2014, 4, 20,11,48,33);
moment().format();
var mome=moment(day);
$('span').text(day);
$('p').text(mome.format("MMM D"));
});
```

Comment: The `Date` object uses months 0-11.  4 = May.  Apr would be 3.  But yes, this demonstrates that it appears to be working just fine.

Answer (score 1):

What you described isn't possible, and Rodrigo's example shows how it works.  However, *today* (the day you're writing this) is June 25th, so that's the source of the value.

You are likely either calling `moment()` without a parameter, or `date_var` is undefined.

Are you sure you didn't accidentally write:

```
moment().format('MMM D');
```

Or is `date_var` declared somewhere that goes out of scope before you pass it to moment?  Something would have to account for it being undefined.